# MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)

Tags: mysql, mamp, sequelpro

the above problem has few solutions here but I couldn't get any of them working so asking.

I have installed mamp and also sequel pro. I am trying to connect using sequel pro but I am getting this error. The whole error is

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary 
privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)
```

This is the first time I am trying to connect via standard connection.

I tried socket connection it works but I cannot connect the database with my nodejs application. Thanks

Comment: Is MySQL running?  Is it listening on 127.0.0.1?  Is your application on the same machine as the database?

Comment: yes to all questions :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had same experience using Sequel Pro.
Go to **Preferences** (Sequel Pro) => **Network** and increase the timeout seconds to maybe 30.
That solved my issue.
[image]